# Is it possible to animate dom reorderings with framer motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

How can I animate (or transition) dom reordering with framer motion? I've read about a technique called the FLIP (mentioned [here](https://medium.com/developers-writing/animating-the-unanimatable-1346a5aab3cd) but I am unsure how I would go about implementing this into framer motion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve by adding `layout` prop to your motion component. Make sure you use version of framer-motion 2.0 and above, because below that it used to be `layoutTransition={transition object}`.

See the working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-reorder-animation-forked-4jbqh?file=/src/Example.tsx